# Joining JSON array with another table

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

My data is in array format like [1,2,3] how to join with another table. Here the query i am trying:

```
select  
   RCM.header_details->'auditAssertion'as auditassertion
from masters."RCM" RCM
   left join reference."AUDIT_ASSERTION_APPLICATION" as AAA on AAA.id=RCM.header_details->'auditAssertion'
```

Comment: What is the exact data type of that column? Native arrays in Postgres are displayed using curly braces, e.g. `{1,2,3}` the square brackets would indicate a `jsonb` (or `json`)  column

Comment: actually RCM  is table name and header_details(jsonb) is column name   and   "auditAssertion": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "4"
    ]

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name pls suggest me proper solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `?` operator to check if a value belongs to json(b) array:

```
select m.header_details->'auditAssertion'as auditassertion
from masters.rcm m
left join reference.audit_assertion_application a 
    on m.header_details->'auditAssertion' ? a.id::text
```

For performance, Postgres would support the following index:

```
create index on masters.rcm using gin ((header_details->'auditAssertion'));
```

Comment: but my data in jsonb type pls help me how to join.

Comment: @RAHULSONI: yes, this solution is for `jsonb`.

Comment: but it not working  still give ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb ? bigint
LINE 4:     on m.header_details->'auditAssertion' ? a.id 
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 176

Comment: @RAHULSONI: ah ok. Consider: `m.header_details->'auditAssertion' ? a.id::text` instead (I updated my answer).

Comment: thanks, @GMB but given data like [1,2,3,4]   here 1 and 2 and 3 is id of reference.audit_assertion_application  show name with as is it with comma separated